# How to find the private key from Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm

Tags: python, encryption, private-key

I am trying to figure out how to find the private key using the forumula on wikipedia.

I read some articles on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm
like this one.

My task is to find the private key :
I have given two messages and their according signatures. To save on randomness, only
the first nonce is generated randomly. The nonce for the second signature is derived from the previous
nonce as k = a · k + b mod n, with (a = 2, b = 1). Recover the private key d .

```
    (r1, s1) = sigdecode_string(sig1, curve.order)
    (r2, s2) = sigdecode_string(sig2, curve.order)


    z1 = int.from_bytes(hashfunc(f1).digest(), 'big')
    z2 = int.from_bytes(hashfunc(f2).digest(), 'big')

    n = curve.order
```

I tried to recover my two k's first with:

```
k1 = (z1-z2) * inverse_mod(s1-s2,n) %n
k2 = (2*k1+1) % n
d = (k1 * k2) % n
```

I dont know where my mistake are... Can someone point it out?

Comment: I don't see any justification for believing that `k1 = (z1-z2) * inverse_mod(s1-s2,n) %n` is correct. The formula in the wikipedia article is only valid when k1==k2, exactly. Your k's are related in a more complicated way, therefore you must derive new formulae for your solver.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk do you know how to derive the new formular correctly? Sitting here for a while to figure it out

Comment: I took a quick look at it and it appears to be much, much, more difficult. Not only are the k's different, but the r's are too, since the they are a function of the k's. I have not tried to solve it.